# about Assembly instruction of testl

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm reading Chapter3 Machine-Level Representation of Programs of CSAPP.

```
testl S2, S1
```

the above instruction based on S2&S1.So 
`testl %eax, %eax` to see whether %eax is negative, zero, or positive.
I don't understand this usage.Please give me some explanation, thank you.

Comment: `Please give me some explanation`... It's in the CPU manual, in the chapter explaining the `test` instruction.

Comment: Thank you,I will read the CPU manual

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TEST instruction is the same as the AND instruction except that it does not store the result.  It only modifies the flags.  It modifies the following flags: sign, parity, zero, carry (always 0) and overflow (always 0).

```
testl %eax, %eax
jz    zeroLabel     ; jump if EAX is zero
js    negLabel      ; jump if EAX is negative
jns   posLabel      ; jump if EAX is positive
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's just to set a flag, the following instruction used after such usage is usually a conditional jump that checks the flags. Testing a register against itself is just to set the cpu flags (neg, zero, pos like you mentioned).

The test instruction does S1 AND S2, so essentially EAX AND EAX is just EAX.